Error 'Table must be specified for selection' in SQL Query in SAP Business One
I am working on a SQL query in SAP Business One, and I keep encountering the following error:

Table must be specified for selection.

The query I am using is as follows:
SELECT  
      o."DocNum",
      (
            SELECT TOP 1 w1."ItemCode"
            FROM WOR1 w1
            WHERE w1."DocEntry" = o."DocEntry"
              AND (w1."LineNum" IS NULL OR w1."LineNum" = '')
            ORDER BY w1."LineNum"
        ) AS "WOR1_ItemCode",
      t."U_Material_Laenge",
      w."PlannedQty"
      
FROM    WOR1 w
        JOIN "WRE_PPS_WorkstepPlanning" p ON p."PODocEntry" = w."DocEntry"
                                        AND p."POLineNum" = w."LineNum"
        JOIN OWOR o ON o."DocEntry" = w."DocEntry"
        JOIN OITM i2 ON i2."ItemCode" = w."ItemCode"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "WRE_POLineWorkstepStatus" ws ON ws."PODocEntry" = w."DocEntry"
                                                    AND ws."POLineNum" = w."LineNum"
        LEFT JOIN "OITT" t ON o."ItemCode" = t."Code"
        
WHERE   
      o."Status" IN ('P', 'R')
      AND COALESCE(ws."Status", 'OPEN') = 'OPEN'
      AND w."ItemCode" LIKE '[%0]'
      AND i2."ItemName" LIKE '[%1]'

Every time I try to execute this query, I receive the error mentioned above. I suspect it might be related to the subquery in the SELECT clause or possibly due to the way I'm using the JOIN conditions, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause.
SAP Business One Version 10.
Database: SQL Server.
Objective: I want to retrieve the document number (o."DocNum"), the first item code (w1."ItemCode") from the WOR1 table where specific conditions are met, along with other details such as t."U_Material_Laenge" and w."PlannedQty".
Question:
Could someone please explain why this error is occurring and how I can resolve it? Is there something specific to SAP Business One SQL syntax or the way subqueries are handled that I need to consider?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I don't believe you should be using quotes around your table and field names.  Double-quoted strings in SAP are literal character strings.

Hi Tim, thank you for your comment. I have removed the double quotes from the table and field names as suggested, but unfortunately, I'm still encountering the same error: "Table must be specified for selection."

Concerning "it might be related to the subquery", it's easy to check whether the error is due to the subquery by removing it and see if the syntax error is still here.

in this block of your query
WHERE
o."Status" IN ('P', 'R')
AND COALESCE(ws."Status", 'OPEN') = 'OPEN'
AND w."ItemCode" LIKE '[%0]'
AND i2."ItemName" LIKE '[%1]'

change to
WHERE
o."Status" IN ('P', 'R')
AND COALESCE(ws."Status", 'OPEN') = 'OPEN'
AND o."ItemCode" LIKE '[%0]'
AND i2."ItemName" LIKE '[%1]'

in the line,

AND w."ItemCode" LIKE '[%0]'
was changed to
AND o."ItemCode" LIKE '[%0]'

o. before ItemCode to explicitly reference the "OWOR" table in the condition, this should resolve the error in your query

Hi Derwyn, thank you for your help. I have modified the query by changing the reference to ItemCode from the WOR1 table to the OWOR table as suggested, so that it now explicitly references o.ItemCode in the WHERE clause. However, I'm still encountering the same error: "Table must be specified for selection."I believe the problem might be related to the subquery in the SELECT clause, but I'm unsure how to adjust it to avoid this error. If anyone has insights on handling subqueries in SAP Business One SQL or other suggestions, I would greatly appreciate the help.
